# How to read user input from terminal before pressing enter using node and javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, terminal, stdin, keypress

How to read user input from terminal before pressing enter using node and javascript?

I have made a simple javascript application which uses process.stdin or readline to get user input, but I don't want the user to have to submit their input with enter/return.  I'd like to read user input on keydown/keypress.  Is this possible?  How might I accomplish this?  Thanks!

Requirements:

- javascript, node
- from terminal
- user not required to submit string with enter/return

Prefer:

- less libraries, more vanilla javascript
- handles any key: letters, numbers, arrow keys, modifiers

Comment: Listen for the "data" event -> `process.stdin.on("data", console.log)`

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it could be with the [`iohook` package](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook).

The native Node.JS way to do it would be like this.

```js
require("readline").emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

process.stdin.on("keypress", (char, evt) => {
  console.log("=====Key pressed=====");
  console.log("Char:", JSON.stringify(char), "Evt:", JSON.stringify(evt));

  if (char === "h") console.log("Hello World!");
  if (char === "q") process.exit();
});
```

The first line, `require("readline").emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin)` makes `process.stdin` emit keypress events, as it normally does not emit the event.

The second, `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)` makes `process.stdin` a raw device. In a raw device configured stream, key press events are emitted on a per character basis, instead of emitting per enter key press.

Then, the `keypress` event listener is added onto `process.stdin` to handle keypresses.

### Note

When `process.stdin` is converted to a raw device, `Ctrl+C` does not emit a `SIGINT` signal, in other words, `Ctrl+C` will not stop the program. This means that you will need to manually bind a key to exit.

Comment: "An easy way to do it could be with the iohook package." A whole package for this litle task that can be done in 10 lines of code seems a bit over kill. Where come this "install package xy" for every litle task from? You clearly dont have to re-invent the wheel, but the use of a package for that is just wrong. Especially, when op writes: "less libraries, more vanilla javascript"

Comment: @Marc It was only a suggestion, and I did include a native way.

Comment: Though I agree with Marc on the whole package ordeal, you did deliver, Sean. Thanks!